# Edge pinned site is not loading notifications

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-edge, live-tile

Im coding a web application that should be pinnable to start menu and should updating a text information by the setup.
Just like there:
[MSDN IE11 Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg183312(v=vs.85).aspx)

In Windows 8.1 desktop and phone it is working well, but on Windows 10 desktop and phone it just do not try (according to server log file) to load XML file mentoined in msapplication-notifications meta tag.

Problem is there is no such documentation for Edge browser, or Im unable to find out...

Is there anybody with such experience?

BR, Jan

Comment: Is the frequency set up correctly? [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255024(v=vs.85).aspx#msapplication-notification) mentions the default is one day polling interval. What's interesting is that according to the note at the end of the linked section it should be supported on Windows 10 only, so the other way around from what you're seeing.

Comment: Im using 30, its a minimum possible, but it should load the XML in time the page is pinned, but nothing happens...

Comment: Can you try using `msapplication-config` instead of the individual meta tags and see if the config file gets hit?

Comment: Also see if `mssitepinned` document event is called in JavaScript at all when you pin the site.

Comment: msapplication-config is way that I used before, but it seems it is working with the same results - tilecolor and icon are loaded correctly but notification xml has no hits in server logs. Im linking the XML in absolute way.

Comment: Can you use `regedit` to delete all subkeys of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\wpnidm` and try pinning the site again? Maybe it's a caching issue, other than that I don't know what else could help. The JS event did get called or not?

Comment: Also, this goes without saying, but triple check the XML URL. Watch out for maybe using HTTPS when in reality the server doesn't support it and typos. You could also try serving the XML file from localhost to remove any network-related doubts.

Comment: And excuse me, Im Javascript negative, how can I catch that event.?

Comment: @regedit, I have deleted all the subkeys, behavior is not changed, no subkey was created, since I pinned the site again.

Comment: I have copied the url from F12 tools and paste it to the browser and that works... Im pretty sure about that there is no typo. Site and file is on the same http site.

Comment: You need to use F5 in regedit to see the new subkey. As for the JavaScript, check out the *JavaScript* code block in your link. Calling `window.external.msStartPeriodicTileUpdateBatch` might work, if even that doesn't, it's probably an Edge bug you're dealing with if it works without change on Windows 8.

Comment: There is no activity in regedit, even if Im pressing F5... Huh, so Im waiting for next Windows 10 update praying for that anybody will handle it ;-)

Comment: Please remember to answer this question if you figure out a workaround or if it gets fixed in a next release of Windows. Good luck!

Comment: OK, thank you for your effort!

Comment: Any luck with this? Just seeing it myself. If you do get it working, you'll want to [update your tile definitions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/archived/archived-adaptive-tile-templates-schema-and-documentation-10586/)

Comment: [There's a microsoft answers post here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/edge-pinned-sites-live-tiles/7934e54b-b631-4b76-9ddf-ec674a689053) where the problem is dismissed as off-topic...

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was either:

- fixed in Windows 10 version 1607 (but broken in 1511), having tested this on another device
- only a problem on some broken windows installations in the first place

Either way, it seems this now works correctly.

Windows 10 brings in some [new tile definitions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/archived/archived-adaptive-tile-templates-schema-and-documentation-10586/) (adaptive tiles) for these notification files, but remains able to render the old definitions